# pass multiple params in services in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jakarta-ee

I'm using angularjs with wildfly v8.2. I have a problem when try to pass multiple params in services in angularjs using get rest services. I've got this error : "Bad arguments passed to org.jboss.resteasy.spi.metadata.ResourceMethod@7a3ab29a" ( null, java.lang.Integer 1 ). How do i pass multiple parameter using get in angularjs. Anyone..

Below is my codes:

**services.js**

```
authListing: function (id, page,  succFn) {

    return $http.get(services.path + 'student/listing', {params: {page: page, id: id}}).success(succFn).error(cmnSvc.errorHandler);
}
```

**rest.java** //endpoint

```
@Path("/listing")
@GET
public Response listing(@QueryParam("id") String id, @QueryParam("page") int page) {
   //Some method here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the call with Angular correctly. However, I suspect you are passing in either a `null` or `undefined` argument based on the error message:

> "Bad arguments passed to
>   org.jboss.resteasy.spi.metadata.ResourceMethod@7a3ab29a" ( **null**,
>   java.lang.Integer 1 )

My guess is that your endpoint isn't meant to take a null value for `id` and that is why it is puking.

You should be able to figure this out pretty quickly by simply opening up the developer tools in your browser, and inspecting the XHR request made to the server.

If it looks something like this: `student/listing?id=undefined&page=1` then you know you have a problem.

Comment: It seems like i'm passing the null id value to the params.  Ive already checked it. Solved.Thanks